# Django Search Query Fails

Tags: django, search, django-templates, django-views

I've implemented this search feature on a small site I'm working on and I am having problems when I carry out a search query. This is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 68, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 68, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 272, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 169, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 203, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/PycharmProjects/first_django_dev/apps/photos/views.py", line 113, in search_photos
    'search_query': search_query
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py", line 44, in render
    return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 188, in render_to_string
    return t.render(context_instance)
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 123, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 117, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 744, in render
    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 73, in render_node
    result = node.render(context)
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 127, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 117, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 744, in render
    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 73, in render_node
    result = node.render(context)
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 64, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 744, in render
    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 73, in render_node
    result = node.render(context)
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 311, in render
    return self.nodelist_true.render(context)
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 744, in render
    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 73, in render_node
    result = node.render(context)
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 227, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render(context))
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 915, in render
    resolved_vars = [var.resolve(context) for var in self.vars_to_resolve]
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 653, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "/Users/glosseyvilly/Desktop/web_dev/ccdev/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 692, in _resolve_lookup
    raise VariableDoesNotExist("Failed lookup for key [%s] in %r", (bit, current)) # missing attribute
TemplateSyntaxError: Caught VariableDoesNotExist while rendering: Failed lookup for key [user] in u"'uploaded_photos/Published/2011/December/21/image_5.jpeg'"
```

This is my view function:

```
def search_photos(request):
    """

    """
    search_query = ''
    results = None
    if ('q' in request.GET) and request.GET['q'].strip():
            search_query = request.GET['q']
        photo_query = get_query(search_query, ['caption',])
        results = Photo.objects.filter(photo_query).order_by('-date_added')

    return render(request, 'photos/search.html', {
        'results': results,
        'search_query': search_query
    })
```

NB: The traceback highlights `'search_query': search_query` being a possible error and I'm not sure why.

EDIT:  Here is a link to my search.html template :  gist.github.com/1524911

Comment: The error is in your template. You should post that. (If you had `TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True` in your settings.py, it would highlight the relevant line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to format the error message as a code block.
2. The specific error is at the end of the traceback: **Failed lookup for key [user] in u"'uploaded_photos/Published/2011/December/21/image_5.jpeg'"** which occurred in `_resolve_lookup`. This is the routine that does the variable value fetching for templates.

I would take a hard look at the template. Pay special attention to any tricky loop references or template tags that might be doing strange lookups (e.g `{% expr %}` comes to mind). Let us know what you come up with.

**Update:**

My money is on the line:

```
     {% phileo_widget result.user result %}
```

Does the `result` object have an attribute named `user`?

Comment: OMG I can't believe I missed that. THANK YOU! :)

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't your method take `self` as its first parameter?:

```
def search_photos(self):
```

So, you access the `request` object with:

```
request = self.request
```